# How to convert background image CSS property to <Img /> element?

Tags: css, gridsome

I am building a site that is generated through a static generator ([Gridsome](https://gridsome.org/docs/images/), a Gatsby alternative). One of the features of this static site generator is that it outputs an optimized progressive image (resizes and crops in real time).

A typical image component will look like this:

`<g-image src="~/image.png" width="500"/>`

`~` is an alias to my  `/src/` folder.

Docs with more details about how to use this component is here: [Gridsome -- Images](https://gridsome.org/docs/images/)

With that said, **I want to convert my CSS background image to the `<img>` element so I can take advantage of the progress image feature. Does anyone know how I can go about converting the below CSS and getting the image into the `<g-image>` element?** Note: I am using CSS pseudo properties to slant the header for artistic reasons.

Here's my code (with [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ay74xrp9/)):

> HTML:

```
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
    <aside class="h1 tagline"><em>We are ACME.
      <br /> Some tagline</em>
      </aside>
      <p class="text-white pad">Snappy text here to explain more about this site.</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

> CSS:

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  height: 40em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Create angled background with 'before' pseudo-element */
.header::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 6em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50em;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: skewY(-3.5deg);
    background: linear-gradient(to left,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0,0,0,1)), url('https://www.fillmurray.com/g/2000/1000') no-repeat left 10rem;
}
```